# Change ONLY Marker type without re-plotting using Matplotlib - Resolved

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting a simple 2D line as shown below. I need to change ONLY the marker type of the EXISTING 2D line (without re-plotting using X and Y data). How can it be done?

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line2D,=ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3],marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

An Update, I found the resolution. Below is the solution to change ONLY marker type on an EXISTING line:

```
line2D.set_marker('+')
```

Comment: Your code seems to show that you have set the marker to the 'o' value and you have a commented out version that employs the '+' value.  What is it you are trying to do, that you haven't been able to do?

Comment: I have marker type 'o' initially, but on click of a button, it should change to marker type '+' but without re-plotting. I mean, My X and Y data is so huge, so I actually don't want to use the command ax.plot() but want to change the marker type to '+' of the existing plot.

Comment: I have 4 buttons in my main GUI, where 4 buttons when clicked should create 4 different marker types on the same plot. Everytime, I don't want to use plot command as my data can be so huge. Is there any way that I can change ONLY the marker of an EXISTING plot?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible, you might look at the underlying code in matplotlib to see how they display the markers and roll your own.